# How to place 2 div one next the other one

Tags: html, css, highcharts

Followed a lot of solution I want to display my graph like this:

> g1 g2
>   g3 g4

So I did this HTML:

```
<div class="x_content">
                      <div class="tableChart">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 caseR">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartMem}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 caseL">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartCPU}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 caseR">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartNet}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 caseL">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartDisk}}</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

With the following CSS who should place the container as I want to:

```
.highcharts-container{
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
}

.caseR, .caseL{
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
}
.caseR{
  float: right !important;
}
.caseL{
  float:left !important;
}
```

But I have this:
[image]

So it's right because I have 2 containers, but the graph inside each of them shouldn't be in a list but 1-2 then 3-4 bellow.

Comment: Just set a style display = inline-block;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `width: 50%;` of the charts and make them display: `inline-block;` If I understood you correctly.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 49%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">test</div>
<div id="2">test</div>
<div id="3">test</div>
<div id="4">test</div>
```